# selecting multiple classes in jQuery and find element width on this instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried searching for two hours but couldn't find the exact answer.
I am trying to do the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.class1, .class2').each(function (){
      var Width1 = $(this).find('.class1').width();
      var Width2 = $(this).find('.class2').width();
      // do stuff here...
    });
}
```

I want to select two classes, then retrieve width of the elements of the current instance to two different variables, there are thousands of elements with class1 and class2. Class 2 is not a subclass of Class 1, selection seems to be valid, but vars are undefined after execution, why is it not working?

Comment: Please show us more code, including the HTML

Comment: This seems like a XY question as it's an odd requirement. I'd suggest using `map()` to build an array of the widths of all the elements, but it may be beneficial if you could explain why you believe you need to do this, as I'm certain there's a better way

Comment: In your code `$(this)` is an element matching the selector, so `.find(".class1")` will look inside each element for an element with that class.  You've just got your logic wrong.  I agree with Rory though ^^ This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: `.filter('.class1')` instread of `.find('.class1')`

Comment: Did you mean your selector to be `$(".class1.class2")`?  Without HTML showing what you're expecting to select, it's hard to tell.  `.class1,.class2` (ie with a comma) will find all elements that have *either* - without a separator (no space either) will find all elements that have *both* (which your following code implies you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks all for answering. I am trying to apply padding to all elements with .class1 based on calculation of widths by Width1 - Width2. 
var paddingSize = "+=" + (coverWidth - textWidth) / 2;

I got a little bit closer with applying filter, thanks! Additional question, How would I then apply .css to only class1 element? I am trying to do:
$(this).filter(".class1").css( "padding-left", paddingSize );
But it does not get applied.

Answer (score 0):

As you said `.class1` is not child of `.class2` so .find wont work. You need to check if current element is `class1` then assign its value to `width1` other assign value to `width2`. Use `.is()` to do this:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.class1, .class2').each(function (){

      var Width1, Width2;

      if($(this).is(".class1")) 
         Width1 = $(this).width();
      else 
         Width2 = $(this).width();

    });
}
```